# Не работает PyQt6 в Windows 7

Tags: python, pyqt5, windows-7, pyqt6, qt6

Код:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = QWidget()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

Ошибка:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "D:\Програмування\python_projects\pyqt\main.py", line 1, in <module>
>     from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWidgets: Не найдена указанная процедура.
> ```

У меня стоит *Windows 7*, python3.8.10, PyQt6-6.1.0. 
Если тот же кот но с PyQt5, то всё работает

Answer (score 2):

**`Qt6`** никогда не предназначался для работы с более ранними версиями,
чем **`Windows 10`**, как объяснялось в раннем [сообщении в блоге о хостах и ​​​​целях](https://www.qt.io/blog/qt6-development-hosts-and-targets),
и как можно увидеть в официальной документации [о поддерживаемых платформах](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/supported-platforms.html).

Если вам нужно, чтобы ваша программа также работала в **`Windows <10`**,
вы должны использовать **`Qt5`**.